# How do you beat the dungeon gurdian in Terraria mobile? If you can, what does it drop?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I looked all over the internet to find some help on this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it, many Holy Hand Grenades, Turtle armour, Terra Blade, Minions, Frost Hydras, Teleporters, grav potions and three other people.

He drops a bone key, like normal.

Picture of me with the pet he gives you:
[image: Selfie with the skeleton head that the bone key gives you]

Answer (score 0):

From what I've heard, it is designed to be unkillable. But it's not completely unkillable. Upon touching your player it deals 9999 damage and has so much defense that even lategame items only deal 1 damage per hit. So, using a good pair of wings, a very long platform and the Piranha Gun you can kill him with a specific strategy: Lure him out of the dungeon and immediately start flying. He will take the most direct path toward you, so zig zag. Latch the Piranha Gun onto him the instant you can, and keep the piranha stuck to him. No matter what modifier you have, it will only deal 1 damage. So you simply keep weaving and hope for the best! When you've killed him he drops a Bone Key, which summons a skeletal Dungeon Guardian pet.

Answer (score -2):

There are ways to kill him it requires teleporters and insane damage. There is no drop. I would just listen to the other answer.